# How to stop Visual Studio 2017 opening source code in split screen mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When opening source code from certain dialogues, Visual Studio adds the source code module to same tab list rather than adding a tab to the main source code window.

Any idea how I can stop it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Menu 'Window' > 'Reset Window Layout'